# CentOS 6.6 (Final) - yum kernel upgrade troubles

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, kernel, rpm

Well-being everybody,

I'm a SysAdmin Junior managing 3 `CentOS` Virtual (Web)Servers,
this morning I'm facing some troubles with package manager `yum`. As usual operation, this morning I've run the command `yum update && yum upgrade`, on one of the 3 CentOS (the younger) no problem, everything fine. But on the "oldest" 2 Servers (not that old, running from 1.5 year, but probably not outstanding) seems there are some problem upgrading the kernel, I've googled and it seems it's just my problem, following the console output:

```
# yum update && yum upgrade
```

.
.
.

```
Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kernel-2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64 (centos6_x86_update)
       Requires: dracut-kernel >= 004-388.el6
       Installed: dracut-kernel-004-356.el6_6.3.noarch (@centos6_x86_update)
           dracut-kernel = 004-356.el6_6.3
       Available: dracut-kernel-004-336.el6.noarch (centos6_x86_update)
           dracut-kernel = 004-336.el6
       Available: dracut-kernel-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch (centos6_x86_update)
           dracut-kernel = 004-336.el6_5.2
       Available: dracut-kernel-004-356.el6.noarch (base)
           dracut-kernel = 004-356.el6
       Available: dracut-kernel-004-356.el6_6.1.noarch (centos6_x86_update)
           dracut-kernel = 004-356.el6_6.1
       Available: dracut-kernel-004-356.el6_6.2.noarch (centos6_x86_update)
           dracut-kernel = 004-356.el6_6.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've readed the [documentation](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/rpm.8.html) in order to try to understand what the advised commands above here was going to do, and since it didn't seems dangerous to me, I've runned them, but really nothing changed. The problem remain...

Does somebody can give me a shove?

THANKS in advance

that the wind will be favorable to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a problem with your mirror or your yum-cache, as `dracut-kernel 004-388.el6` should be available, at least it is for me:

```
=============================================================================================================
 Package                        Arch               Version                            Repository        Size
=============================================================================================================
Installing:
 dracut-kernel                  noarch             004-388.el6                        base              26 k
```

Clean your yum cache and try again:

`yum clean all && yum update`

P. S.:

`yum update && yum upgrade` doesn't make sense, the only difference between these commands is the implied `obsoletes` flag. This is NOT like apt-get (`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`).

Comment: Thank you very much, `yum clean all && yum update` solved it! you are great, and you caught me, I was abit to apt package manager and I was keeping use the command `yum update && yum upgrade` , grateful for your advice. Would also upvote but not enough reputation on ServerFault

Comment: got enough reputation! : )))

Answer (score 1):

Running `yum clean all && yum update` did not help me. I tried:

```
yum remove dracut
yum install dracut
yum clean all
yum install dracut
```

But it was always saying that there is no package `dracut` available. So the only way was to install it manually:

```
wget ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/Packages/dracut-kernel-004-388.el6.noarch.rpm
wget ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/Packages/dracut-004-388.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh dracut-004-388.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh dracut-kernel-004-388.el6.noarch.rpm
yum install kexec-tools
```